# How do I stop an action in a loop?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to create a script that opens my online classes automatically. I wrote this code:

```
import webbrowser
import datetime
import time

now = time.strftime("%D, %H:%M")

lesson1 = "03/09/21, 15:38"
lesson2 = "03/10/21, 15:39"
lesson3 = "03/10/21, 15:40"

while True:
    while now != lesson1 and now != lesson2 and now != lesson3:
        print ("Waiting, the current time is " + now)
        now = time.strftime("%D, %H:%M")
        time.sleep(1)

    if now == lesson1:
        print ("LESSON IS OPENING :D")
        webbrowser.open("https://google.com")

    if now == lesson2:
        print ("LESSON IS OPENING :D")
        webbrowser.open("https://google.com")

    if now == lesson3:
        print ("LESSON IS OPENING :D")
        webbrowser.open("https://google.com")
```

Now, the problem is that the first if-statement is executed endlessly, I want to make it execute only one time, than wait until now == lesson2 and execute the second if etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in each iteration you are checking if current time is equal to lesson time which causes program to open browser numerous times. Since you are working with `hours/minutes`, making program sleep 1 min once your current lesson starts would prevent it.

Sample Input:

```
import webbrowser
import datetime
import time

now = time.strftime("%D, %H:%M")
print("Current Time -- ", now)

lesson1 = "03/10/21, 11:14"
lesson2 = "03/10/21, 11:15"
lesson3 = "03/10/21, 11:16"


while True:
    while now != lesson1 and now != lesson2 and now != lesson3:
        print ("Waiting, the current time is " + now)
        now = time.strftime("%D, %H:%M")
        time.sleep(1)
        
    if now == lesson1:
        print("Opening Google")
        webbrowser.open("https://google.com")
        time.sleep(60)
        now = time.strftime("%D, %H:%M")

    if now == lesson2:
        print("Opening Youtube")
        webbrowser.open("https://youtube.com")
        time.sleep(60)
        now = time.strftime("%D, %H:%M")

    if now == lesson3:
        print("Opening Facebook")
        webbrowser.open("https://facebook.com")
        time.sleep(60)
        now = time.strftime("%D, %H:%M")
```

---

Sample output:

```
Current Time -- 03/10/21, 11:13
Waiting, the current time is 03/10/21, 11:13
Opening Google
Opening Youtube
Opening Facebook
```

Comment: I tried to change the links in each if-statement and just realized that the script opens only the first one every 60 seconds and it doesn't go through the next if-statement

Comment: @MatteoPassaro, this happens when 2 lessons are set without any time in between because we never update `now`  variable once joining lesson. We should be updating `now` after joining each class too. Edited answer

Comment: And how am I supposed to do that?

Comment: @MatteoPassaro I have edited answer, check it again to see if that resolves your issue

Comment: I actually came up with that before, but it doesn't work :c

Comment: Can you provide some sample example to test it out because it worked as it is intended when I tried

Comment: Just try to write 3 different links instead of "google.com" and you'll notice that it doesn't work as it should

Comment: @MatteoPassaro, unfortunately I couldn't reproduce it. I have edited code and added my sample input/output, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to schedule your code to run at certain times. I recommend using the **[APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)** library. Very easy to use and is efficient.